# Is "new" still not recommended in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, new-operator

So I see plenty of JavaScript code out there that uses "new" when making constructors. After reading part of JavaScript the Good Parts it seems that using "new" isn't the cat's pajamas. That was 4 years ago though... Is it still not recommended? What is the current standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since when is `new` not recommended? D. Crockford has a valid point and a strong opinion but `new` is part of the language and it's very much being used in many projects. `new` is part of the prototype inheritance model, and must be used to create new instances with a constructor function. Crockford points out a purely functional approach using the `this` context appropriately and `return this` to be able to inherit properties and methods between children objects. It's a different solution to a common problem, but it doesn't mean that `new` shouldn't be used. In fact, one of the most copy/pasted JS snippets of all times is Crockford's, the `object.create` polyfill, and it uses `new`:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Comment: That is true! Well in his book he mentions "Use of this style of constructor functions is not recommended" (the style that use new). Then he goes on to describe other solutions. That is why I brought up the question.

Comment: He doesn't recommend it because it can lead to confusion in some cases, but there are other common practices to avoid confusion like capitalizing your constructor functions. You could say the same thing about Crockford's not recommending to use `++` and `--`...

Comment: Both of which I think are useable but I stopped using them because everyone I work with decided to stop using these operators.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing much has changed since 2008 apart from the Crockford-influenced `Object.create` making its way into ECMAScript 5: `new` still has the same behaviour and drawbacks that Douglas Crockford has forcefully pointed out. My own opinion is that he has rather overstated the problems and turned developers against a useful operator, so I continue to use it without issue; I would suggest other developers make up their own mind rather than blindly internalize and regurgitate (the admittedly admirable) Crockford.

Comment: I agree. I think he probably should've said that we should use it with the knowledge that there are drawbacks but it is useable.