# Typescript, import, "new", constructor and interfaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, constructor

The problem is not about the "new" keyword in the ["problematic aspect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878924/is-new-still-not-recommended-in-javascript), but more in the practical approach.

I'm fighting a bit with my C# and JavaScript mindsets when defining classes (ES2015). In C# I use dependency injection to inject the dependencies in the class' constructor. In JavaScript, due to its prototypical nature, I learned there's no need for you to inject a dependency into the constructor; you can safely use `import`, because you can later mock the method later for Unit Testing.

Therefore many modules "just work" out of the box, without the need to instantiate them. (Node modules are examples)

I've been using TypeScript in my project. As you know, you can use Interfaces with it. What I’ve been doing as of now, is setting the interface as a property and then setting the class in question to it.

To better illustrate what I'm saying, imagine I have class A:

```
class A implements Letter {
    hello(){
        console.log("Hello World");
    }
}
```

And its interface "Letter":

```
interface Letter {
    hello(): void
}
```

Then I have a class "Book" which uses the approach I'm saying.

```
export class Book{
    letter : Letter
    constructor(){
        this.letter = A; 
    }
    Read(){
        console.log("We're about to read this chapter!");
        this.letter.hello();
    }
}
```

And it can be used like this:

```
import {Book} from './book' 
let book = new Book();
    book.Read();
```

On the other hand, I have "BookVersionJs" who doesn't use any interface and implements it directly:

```
import {A} from './a.ts';

export class BookVersionJs{
    Read(){
        console.log("We're about to read this chapter!");
        A.Hello(); 
    }
}
```

Then we can use it like this:

```
  import {BookVersionJs} from './BookVersionJs'    
    BookVersionJs.Read();
```

But I loose the "theoretical" loose coupling that the interfaces give me. Theoretical because JavaScript could overwrite them with a prototype.

There's a difference in practicality. Which should I aim for in TypeScript/JavaScript? Or is it a matter of opinion?

Comment: You cannot do `A.hello()`, as `A` is a class, not an instance. You need to either do `new A().hello()` or make the `hello` method static.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Oooooohhhhhh I finally got it. The thing is that I was always confused because of the transpiling. This answer goes a lot on what I was trying to say. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534702/node-js-use-of-module-exports-as-a-constructor https://stackoverflow.com/a/20534942/1057052

Comment: Yup. Problem solved. Thanks to your comment I managed to find what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but I can definitely say I like the look of your `Book` example far more than your `BookVersionJs` example (even though both have some syntax errors in there).

Think about reading books.

*BookVersionJs*

```
BookVersionJs.Read();   // "I am reading Book"
```

*Book*

```
let book = new Book();
book.Read();  // "I am reading a Book"
```

Your objects should make sense semantically or anyone else who uses your code will get very confused.

If your concern is testability, then by all means inject the `Letter`.  You can keep `A` as the default type for easier usability in your day-to-day code and supply a different implementation of `Letter` during your unit tests.

```
export class Book{
    letter : Letter;
    constructor(letter: Letter = new A()) { // Note: Assign instance of A, not just A. A is a type, not a value.
        this.letter = letter; 
    }
    Read(){
        console.log("We're about to read this chapter!");
        this.letter.hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch. I did the code really fast on a single document on TypeScript without checking for anything. What I'm really asking is, if the TypeScript/JavaScript way of doing things is better not to instantiate a class and have a static method directly or should I proceed the Java/C# way and "new" the objects?

Comment: It is probably subjective, but I say yes, definitely use `new`; *especially* if you're using TypeScript rather than plain JavaScript.  TypeScript fully embraces the whole class-based approach and to go back to a more functional style would mean using TypeScript is bit redundant and wasteful.